# Issue with Django form POST method

Tags: python, django, forms

I am having a problem with the following view and form.  The form loads correctly however when I edit any of the fields it does not save. After a bit of debugging I think it is due to one of two things: either  `request.method == "POST"` is evaluating to false, or `form.is_valid()` is evaluating to false.  So potentially something wrong with my template or my clean() method?  I've searched previous questions and can't find anything that helps.  I've also checked my clean() method against the Django docs and think it is OK.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def edit_transaction(request, pk):
    transaction = get_object_or_404(Transaction, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST, instance=transaction)
        if form.is_valid():
            transaction = form.save(commit=False)
            transaction.updated = timezone.now()
            transaction.save()
            return redirect('view_transaction_detail', pk=transaction.pk)
    else:
        form = TransactionForm(request=request, instance=transaction)
    return render(request, 'budget/new_transaction.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('title', 'transaction_type', 'category', 'budgeted_amount', 'actual_amount', 'date', 'comments',)

    #new_category field to allow you to add a new category
    new_category = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, label="New Category Title")

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #category is now not a required field because you will use category OR new_category
        self.fields['category'].required=False
        #set to allow use of self.request.user to set user for category
        self.request = request

    def clean(self):      
        category = self.cleaned_data.get('category')
        new_category = self.cleaned_data.get('new_category')
        if not category and not new_category:
            # raise an error if neither a category is selected nor a new category is entered
            raise forms.ValidationError('Category or New category field is required')
        elif not category:
            # create category from new_category
            category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(title=new_category, defaults={'user': self.request.user})
            self.cleaned_data['category'] = category

        return super(TransactionForm, self).clean()
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'budget/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>New transaction</h2>
    <h4>To add a new category, leave Category blank and enter your new category in the New Category Title field</h4>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**update following answer** - accessing request through kwargs

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['category'].required=False
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned on your last question, since you've changed the signature of the form's init method you need to pass the request *both* times you instantiate it. You're only doing so when it is not POST; so, when it is a POST, Python takes the data that you passing and assigns it to the `request` argument, leaving the data itself blank.

```
form = TransactionForm(request, data=request.POST, instance=transaction)
```

Note it is precisely for this reason that is is a bad idea to change the signature; instead, pass `request` as a keyword argument and inside the method get it from `kwargs`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  Can I check my understanding of your last comment please?  Do you mean something along the lines of what I have posted as an update (sorry it won't format correctly with indents in the comment box)?